# There is one concern regarding angular UI-grid

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I want to display only 4 columns, but when I bind the `grdOptions.Data=entity`,
then all fields in entity are converted into a column. Can we prevent it from autogenerating all the columns?

Answer (score 0):

As per the **first** page of [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api):

> ... if you wanted to configure the core ui-grid, you might choose to set some options and columns on your grid (the documentation for these is found in [gridOptions](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions) and [columnDef](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef).

And here's the **first** example:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableSorting: true,
  columnDefs: [ 
    { name: 'field1', enableSorting: false },
    { name: 'field2' },
    { name: 'field3', visible: false }
  ]
};
```